# WMI listing schema information in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm trying to list all of the available fields on a WMI Class using C#.

The closest I've got is listing all of the available equivalent of tables in WMI

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from meta_class");

 foreach (ManagementClass wmiClass in searcher.Get())
 {
     Console.WriteLine(wmiClass["__CLASS"].ToString());
 }
```

However it appears there is no equivalent of this for the fields.

Is this possible or is it just a case of looking up the reference manual to see all of the available fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an instance of the WMI class, then [`System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties.aspx) is a listing of all the properties (WMI doesn't separate properties and fields – being based on COM they're all properties).

[`ManagementClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s54685.aspx) derives from `ManagementBaseObject` so it also has a `Properties` property listing the properties of the WMI class, so to list all the properties:

```
var wmiClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
foreach (var prop in wmiClass.Properties) {
  Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}
```

(Each element of the `Properties` collection is a [`PropertyData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.propertydata.aspx) instance with lots of information about each property.)